# Google App Engine NDB repeated property additional info

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

For example: I have an Article model with a repeated "title" property that stores translations in different languages of the original title:

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

How can I store, besides the title property, the language code of the title, so I can get specific versions of the title, something like this:

```
en_title = article.title['en']
```

It is important to have the same property name since I don't know in what language the article title will be queried by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use repeated structure property:

```
class Title(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty()
  lang = ndb.StringProperty()

class Article(ndb.Model):
  titles = ndb.StructuredProperty(Title, repeated=True)
```

Comment: And how can I get the title of a specific language?

Comment: @andrei The title of the question is a bit misleading, but if you need to have a dict then just use the PicklePropety or JsonProperty as Guido suggested.

Comment: Sorry about the title, I didn't know how else to call this. I still don't know how to solve this. If I store the titles as you suggested I can query efficiently by the title but I can't get a specific title by language on a instance. However, from what I could understand, if I store the title as a PicklePropety or JsonProperty the dict get stored in the datastore as a blob and I bet the query is much slower (that is if I can query by title, since it is a dict don't I have to query by dict key? which will be the language code)

Answer (score 3):

Are you querying on the titles or languages? If not, you can use PickleProperty or JsonProperty to store a dict.

Comment: Yes, querying on the title property is very important and also all the translated titles must have the same property name since I don't know in what language the user will be querying. I think I'll use StructuredProperty and figure out how to get a specific title by language code. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Just write a lookup function that takes a list of Title objects and a language and returns the title for that language (perhaps adding a default language too).